# What can/do astronauts look at with the portable telescopes aboard the ISS?

Tags: iss, space-telescope, telescope

I would like to know what will be the visibility from the portable telescope aboard the International Space Station.

What could they potentially view, and what are (at least some of) the things they are known to have looked at?

Presumably they use it *inside* the ISS and not outside, and are therefore constrained by there needing to be a window providing access, to the sky, and the window should have good optical quality to preserve the resolution of the telescope?

For additional background, see [Is there a telescope on board the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13769/12102)

[image]

Comment: I made an edit to your *really interesting* question, please feel free to roll back or edit further. Here's an example of a photograph taken with an SLR camera and a very big and long focal length lens: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16805/12102 which is arguably also a telescope in some sense.